# Simple python class not working

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble with this class in Python, why is it not working?

```
class Quiz:
    def __init__(self, answer, question):
        self.answer = answer
        self.question = question

    def yesno(self):
        if self.answer == self.question:
        return str("Correct!")
    else:
        return str("Wrong!")

print("Time for a quiz.")

print("What is ((((6^2 * 10) + sqrt((5000*3) - 600)) / 4! ) * 4 ) - log(1 * 10^11)?")
userAnswer = int(input())
question1 = Quiz(userAnswer, 69)
Quiz.yesno()
```

Comment: question1.yesno()

Comment: i can't understand this statement `if self.answer == self.question:` ?

Comment: @KalpeshDusane: It compares if the values of `self.answer` and `self.question` are the same. Of course the naming of those variables is totally wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you need to instantiate the class.  So, `question1.yesno()` is the right way to go when calling the method (you're calling a method on the instance of the object).

Also, you have a small indentation error that could cause some problems further down the road.

```
def yesno(self):
        if self.answer == self.question:
        return str("Correct!")
    else:
        return str("Wrong!")
```

Should actually be:

```
def yesno(self):
            if self.answer == self.question:
               return str("Correct!")
            else:
               return str("Wrong!")
```

Answer (score 1):

`question1.yesno()` would work.

The `yesno()` is a method which can be called by the object of the class. If it had been a static method, `Quiz.yesno()` would have worked.